# Retrieving text from a text file and inputting it to a Text component

Tags: unity, c#, text

I had a suspicion I would come across this problem. I know how to write to the file and read from it, but the following snippet isn't allowing me to input it into a text component.

```
public class EventHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    string _text;
    Text text;
    private void Awake() 
    {
        text = FindObjectOfType<Text>();
    }
    public string Read(string path)
    {
        _text = "";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            _text += reader.ReadLine();
        }
        reader.Close();
        return _text;
    }
    public void chapter_one()
    {
        text.text = Read("Assets/Chapters/chapter_one.txt");
    }
}
```

I'm sure you guys can explain why this isn't working. I already got the reference to the Text component as well.

**Edit**

No errors, file exists, its filled, color is white on black background, chapter_one is the file name and yes chapter_one is called, and I put Debug.Log right in the while loop and out_side of it and I received those logs. My only thoughts are that the string is not getting returned for god knows what reason, or the text component isn't appending the text.

Comment: What do you mean by "this isn't working" ? Have you got any error ? Does the file exist ? Is it empty ? Maybe the font color is not visible ? Are you sure `chapter_one` is called ? Have you tried to put `Debug.Log`s to find where does the problem come from ? We need more details !

Comment: In the `Read` function, I would have initialized `_text` to the empty string, and in the loop, I would have put : `_text += reader.ReadLine();`, else, you override the content of `_text` each iteration.

Comment: That didn't change anything, its still not printing to the screen.

Comment: Could it be that I shouldn't use StreamReader?

Comment: @Gnemlock, yes it is outputting to Debug.Log. I declared `_text` as a global variable such like `string _text` at the beginning of my class. In the Read method, I actually set it to empty string which I will update my question to reflect. The problem seems to be that  `text.text` which is what is grabbing my scene's Text Component, is not receiving `_text`.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem. Copying your code exactly shows the expected result in-editor (though note that in a compiled build you'll want to use Application.dataPath). If you're not getting errors then my first step would be to check the text object in scene is sized & positioned appropriately. If the field is too small then the first line may overflow and not render. Another way to reduce uncertainty is to eliminate the StreamReader from the equation and treat your text file as a [TextAsset](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html), accessing the .text property.

Comment: Oh, no it's just plain not showing up. Meaning it isn't showing up in the Text Component in general. In the editor at runtime, the Text Component is empty when it should have the string that I'm passing to it.

Comment: @Sora, I made some assumptions after confirming your code worked. I decided to post my original comments as an answer.

Comment: Given that the text component does not update at runtime (not having a `Canvas` should not stop that from happening), I believe it is your `GetObjectOfType` call. I personally try to stay away from this function. *In case its not*, I feel we might be moving to far into discussion. Let me know, and well open a chat room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an extensive amount of research over the last two day, the help of all you wonderful people, and a little bit of ingenuity and sacrifice I managed to create a solution. As some reference, it turns out that `chapter_one` was not being called properly, however, even when it was being called properly it wasn't working. So, I ended up using `File.ReadAllText(path)` to get the text in my `.txt`. This is when I found out `chapter_one` wasn't being called correctly. I ended up doing a lot of migrating of various things away from my `EventHandler` and using multiple scripts to achieve what I was doing with just my `EventHandler`. The following code being placed on the Text Component in the scene achieved what I set out to do in the first place:

```
public class Chapter_one : MonoBehaviour
{
    string _text;

    private void Awake()
    {
        chapter_one();
    }
    public void Read(string path)
    {
        _text = File.ReadAllText(path);
    }
    public void chapter_one()
    {
        Read("Assets/Chapters/chapter_one.txt");
        gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = _text;
    }
}
```

Such simple things like this situation, where all that needed to be done was change methods or changing the style of retrieving a particular thing makes things so annoying. Especially when it takes days to figure out the most simplest of problems.

Comment: It only just occurred to me that your not actually calling `chapter_one()` in your provided example (in the actual question). Perhaps it would help to show us how you *were* calling this method? Simply calling it from an `Awake()` method, I have no trouble. It would probably help to know *why* you were having the particularly odd issue, rather than knowing how you could get around it.

Comment: Well, the problem was that I had a GameObject that has the `EventHandler` script on it, this GameObject didn't persist through my scenes, instead there was a new one in every scene(Which I have thus changed). Since that was the case and the `chapter_one` method was called at scene change, it never went through. At the moment, the problem is fixed and probably in a more organized and stable way than keeping everything on the `EventHandler` script. I realize I could switch the method and all it's counterparts back to `EventHandler` now that it persists, but I think it's better this way.

Answer (score 1):

Testing your solution, I find that the script works. You confirm that the text is being *set* from your `StreamReader`, but not transferring to your `Text` component. I can only find two reasons why this might be happening, and both generally fall under how you actually *set up* your initial `Text` component.

---

#### `FindObjectOfType<t>()` will only work if you can *guarantee* that you only have one instance of that `t Type`, or otherwise, do not care about *what* instance you will retrieve.

[As per official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html), `FindObjectOfType<>()` will return *the first active object* of that `Type` that has been loaded in to the scene. In my experience, you can not always reliably assume *what* instance will return, unless you *only* have a single instance of that `Object` in your scene.

That said, there is a much easier way to do this. If your script is attached to the same `GameObject` that holds your intended `Object`, use `GetComponent<Component>`, instead. That way, we look for the `Component` inside the specific `GameObject`. We can have a lot more control over referencing the right `Object`, in this way.

An easier method is to simply link the reference via the Inspector. You can do this by making your `Text` reference `public`, or by using either the `[SerializeField]` or `[ShowInInspector]` tags. The below script will look for a `Text` component *local* to the host `GameObject`, providing it has not already been linked via the Inspector.

```
public class EventHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]Text text;
    // ...

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(text == null)
        {
            text = (Text)GetComponent<Text>();
        }
    }
}
```

#### To be visually displayed, `Text` must be attached to a `Canvas`

`Text` will not display if it does not have a `Canvas` to display to. `Canvas` is a separate `Component`, and is used to display UI. The `Text` `GameObject` must be attached to the `Canvas` `GameObject`, via the Hierarchy. They *can* simply be attached to the same `GameObject`, if preferred.

[image: UI Elements will not display if they are not "attached" to a Canvas component via the Hierarchy.]